# MongoDB auto pushes arrays into data schemas

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm being in a case in which I don't know why or what causes it. I can't find any info on this weird problem. So I'm gonna ask here.

```
//mongoDB data schema
const dataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userID: String,
    userStocks: Array,
    stockMarket: Array,
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Data', dataSchema);
```

The problem then arrives when creating a new collection in the database:

```
var regUser = new Data({
   
});
console.log(regUser); return;
```

The `console.log(regUser)` returns both the `stockMarket` array and `userStock` array as empty arrays.

Why is this? And how do I prevent it?

It works fine with `Number` and `String` type. But with `Array` type it seems to auto insert it for some reason.

I've tried with `delete regUser.stockMarket` but it does nothing despite returning `true` when run. I've also tried removing them with an aggregate using `$unset` and `$merge` but still nothing.

So does anyone have any idea what could be causing this weird case? And how would I fix it?

-----------EDIT-----------
Based on the answer from @HuyPham I found out the problem was that I didn't correctly declare it as in array in the schema constructor. The correct way of doing it was:

```
const dataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   userID: String,
   userstocks: {
       type: Array,
       default: undefined
   },
   stockMarket: {
       type: Array,
       default: undefined
   }
});
```

Comment: May you provide objects you map to `var regUser = new Data()` ?

Comment: @HuyPham It would work as expected if I map to regUser ex.
`var regUser = new Data({userID: '12345'});console.log(regUser); return;`
Would as expected return the object containing userID equal to 1234. However it would still include the two empty arrays userStocks and stockMarket despite me not setting them in the regUser. Is that what you meant for me to answer? Or was the question regarding something else?

Comment: You have defined `Array` type in `mongoose.Schema` in the wrong way. Take a look at [Arrays](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays:~:text=Mongoose%20supports-,arrays,-of%20SchemaTypes%20and) in mongoose docs. In case you receive empty `array` for `userStocks` and `stockMarket` maybe it's take [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instance as `default` value.

Comment: I have updated to the answer below along with a bit of correction advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `Array` type in `mongoose.Schema` in the wrong way. Take a look at [Arrays](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays:%7E:text=Mongoose%20supports-,arrays,-of%20SchemaTypes%20and) in mongoose docs. In case you receive empty `array` for `userStocks` and `stockMarket` maybe it's take [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instance as default value.

In the correct way you found above, make an adjustment from `type: Array` to `type:[]` to prevent unpredictable issues when using JavaScript `Array` instance to set type.

```
const dataSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   userID: String,
   userstocks: {
       type: [],
       default: undefined
   },
   stockMarket: {
       type: [],
       default: undefined
   }
});
```